# How to set vocabulary size in python tokenizers library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

I would like to fit my own tokenizer and use it further for the pre-trained model, however, when fitting a new tokenizer there seems to be no way to choose the vocabulary size. So when I call `tokenizer.get_vocab()` it always returns a dictionary with 30000 elements. How do I change that? Here is what I do:

```
from tokenizers import Tokenizer
from tokenizers.models import BPE
tokenizer = Tokenizer(BPE(unk_token="[UNK]"))

from tokenizers.trainers import BpeTrainer
trainer = BpeTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[PAD]", "[MASK]"])

from tokenizers.pre_tokenizers import Whitespace
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()

tokenizer.train(['transcripts.raw'], trainer) # Here there are no additional arguments for some reason
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use the `vocab_size` parameter of the `BpeTrainer`, which is set by default to 30000:

```py
trainer = BpeTrainer(special_tokens=["[UNK]", "[CLS]", "[SEP]", "[PAD]", "[MASK]"], vocab_size=10)
```

For more information, you can check out the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/tokenizers/python/latest/api/reference.html#tokenizers.trainers.BpeTrainer).